# Using Nodemailer with gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have been reading mulitple forums and tried for many hours to get my Nodemailer app to work and it simply isn't working. I have taken the suggestions from people who were able to get theirs to work but the result is still the same for me. I have posted the error below that I am getting whenever I try to send a POST request on the form I have created.

UPDATE:!!

I have managed to get the code to link up to the email but now I cannot get the data inputted into the contact form to submit to the email. I am somewhat new so if I sound inexperienced, I am. I appreciate the patience. Here is the current code:

```
app.post('/contact',urlencodedParser,(req,res)=>{
    const output= `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
         <li> Name:${req.body.name}</li>
         <li> Email:${req.body.email}</li>
        <li> Message:${req.body.message}</li>

    </ul>

    `;

    async function main(){



    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,

        auth: {
            user:'ME@EMAIL.COM',
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD

        },

    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: req.body.email, // sender address
      to: "me@email.com", // list of receivers
      subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
       html: `${req.body.message}` // html body
    });

    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  }

  main().catch(console.error);


res.render('contact')

})
```

Comment: "and it simply isn't working": Please edit your question to explain more precisely *what* itsn't working. Do you get an error message, which one exactly (please copy/paste it)? If not, what does not work?

Comment: Also, Gmail rejects mail that contains links and hostnames that untrusted.

Comment: I updated my post with the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a forgot password controller which mails the user with a password.
emailConfig.js

```
var email = "xxxx@gmail.com";
const password = "xxxxxx";
const service = "gmail";

module.exports = {
  service: service,
  email: email,
  password: password
}
```

Controller.js

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service : nodeMailerConfig.service,
    auth :{
        user : nodeMailerConfig.email,
        pass : nodeMailerConfig.password
    }
});
    const mailOptions = {
                          from: nodeMailerConfig.email,
                          to: req.body.email,
                          subject: "Forgot Password",
                          html: `<p>Hi ${req.body.email}</p> <br/>
                                  <pre>Your password is ${randomPassword}</pre><br/>
                                  <pre>Cheers, OpenBox Team</pre>`
                          }
                          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(mailerr,info)=> {
                              if(mailerr){
                                res.status(400).json("Unable to send email");
                              }else{
                                res.status(201).json(info);
                              }
                          })
```

Please make sure that you are turning on the insecure email settings in your gmail, else most of the time the mail will be rejected or will be in spam box.